# Partial derivative of a composite function, given the definition of one of the functions

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative

I need to find $\frac{∂f}{∂x}$ of
$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\phi(wx+b)$ where  $\phi(x)=x^2$

I'm looking at something like $\frac{∂f}{∂x} = \frac{∂f}{∂\phi}\frac{∂\phi}{∂x}$, but I'm not sure how to do it mathematically.  Also how would this mapping be described?  "x is mapped by $f$ to another map $\phi$...?"  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you confuse yourself by having $x$ with different meanings?

Using the chain rule may be enough? let $y=wx+b$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\\
=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2y\cdot w\\
=w(wx+b)
$$

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't done these in a while.  This is actually a pre-requisite question for a machine learning course.